# Microsoft Word 2003: very slow and continuously loading something

Tags: microsoft-word, performance

When I start Word without opening any documents it works fast as usual...
When I open documents it starts loading something (I can tell it by the busy shape of the mouse cursor) and never stops...
Also moving word's window becomes very laggy.

I have Office 2003 Service Pack 3 on Windows 7 Ultimate 32 bit, it used to work without problems before...
Any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user profile was corrupted.

I've created a new user profile and migrated the old user in it.